Top is right, the rest is left
What digits should replace the question marks in this approximate sequence (no calculations or mathematics are involved here)?
 9 6 8 7 9 8 8 9 ?
 2 1 1 3 0 4 5 1 ?
 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 5 ?


Just want to add, no calculations or mathematics involved

The question marks should be replaced by:

 6, 1 and 0, stacked in the same way as in the second column.

I first clocked that...

 ...if we read down the columns, these read a lot like times on a clock face: 9:20, 6:10, 8:15, 7:30, 9:00, 8:40, 8:50, 9:15, ?:??. (It's the right digit range, so it's a reasonable connection to make...)

 So I drew them out (very) roughly to see what shapes they made...



 ...and I realised that these looked an awful lot like they might spell something out in flag semaphore, where the positions of the signaller's arms are indicated by the hands on the clock (approximately). Moreover, they spelled out SEMAPHOR?, strongly suggesting that the last numbers should be those that enable a final letter 'E' to be added to the word in order to complete the spelling of 'semaphore'. This would be another "6:10".

The significance of the title...

 ...is that the top digit - the 'hour' in question - is pointed out by the right hand, the others by the flag in the left. (See the diagram in this post for corroboration, figures from Britannica.com.)


Well done :) This is actually the idea I had when I posted the previous one. Same answer, but imo a better puzzle.
